# Line below link on hover

Tags: html, css

How can I add a short line below link ? The line should be visible only on hover. 
I tried with border-bottom, but that way the line is 100% of the link width and I want the line to be **shorter** than the link .

Here is a example image of the effect that I try to make.

[image]

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Where do you want the line to appear? Underneath specific letters?

Comment: title seams easy.... well this was unexpected.

Comment: you could just use :hover background-image:"YOUR-SMALL-line"

Comment: Try using background images, bottom positioned, or even border images.

Comment: Knee jerk thought is that you might need to use a `background-image` on the `:hover` selector.

Comment: [Here's my bid](http://jsfiddle.net/6kpCm/) NOTE: I'm not a UI developer, so this is *most definitely* not x-browser compliant.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try using `::after` pseudo element:

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<a href='#'>Demo Link</a>
```

Comment: It seems that the demo isn't working. I don't see a line when hovering the link

Comment: Are you using an ancient browser that doesn't support pseudo elements?

Comment: It's working fine now, but it's weird that in says border-bottom: 1px but the line is at least 2 or 3px from what i can see

Comment: I think this is by far the best answer! +1

Comment: @user2013488 that's because `border` shorthand adds the 1px border in all directions… if you exactly want a 1px narrow border you can specifically use `border-top` or `border-bottom` :)

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect now

Comment: @user2013488 Can you explain how this is better than my answer.

Comment: @Ruddy in your answer the line has a specific width, if the specified width is too small like 5px and the link is really large, user might not even notice the line. If the line is too long and the link is small, it'll look awkward. Here the lines length adjusts with the link.

Comment: @TJ Oh dear, did you even read the first comment on my answer? Its pretty obvious, the way I did mine is so you can use a **percentage** for it.... [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/pYH36/5/). So you are incorrect about my answer having a fixed width, it takes little knowledge of `CSS` and `HTML` to know a width can have a percentage.

Comment: @Ruddy you're answer doesn't mention or demonstrate using %. Until you explicitly mentioned, i didn't notice any comment, probably same in the case of OP. Hence the OP found my answer useful to him and accepted it. problem solved. [you might want to read this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254790/accepted-answer-vs-voted-answers)

Comment: @TJ There is no need to demonstrate it, as I said anyone that's even looked at `CSS` and `HTML` knows that width can be a percentage. Also this is now more down to the fact you have said I used a fixed width and fail to see it can he a percentage. Thanks for that link, here you should probably [**look at this to help you**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width). And just to point out, my question was aimed at the OP, not you.

Comment: @Ruddy Why didn't you use % at the first place.. or include it in any of the demo's? Because you didn't consider different links initially. You didn't think about % until somebody else pointed it out. (You didn't even bother to update your answer accordingly until now but that's a different story) OP also probably didn't think about it initially, So he accepted an answer that took a different path which considered the scenario when he wanted a solution.

Comment: @TJ `Because you didn't consider different links initially`.... I didn't have to because width can be a percentage. Not sure why you cant get that. I also (again) was asking the OP why your answer is better then mine, that way I can improve my answer. From what your saying I must start teaching the basics in my answer... that's not why this site is here. Also if you want to get to the point of "what the OP wanted" lets see *I want the line to be shorter than the link*... Shall we see if my answer is correct in terms of what the OP wanted. I'm done here, happy coding!

Answer (score 8):

This is something I just thought of, check it out see what you think. So we use `:after` and create a line under the text. This only works if the parent has a width (for centering).

**HTML:**

```
<div>Test</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    width: 30px;
}
div:hover:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/pYH36/2/)

---

**Updated CSS:**

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Not sure why I didnt think of this but you can just use `inline-block` to get it to center without the parent having a width.

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/pYH36/3/)

---

Here is a link using the same method, just incase you got confused.

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/pYH36/4/)

---

So I have now be told I should even point out the most obvious thing so here is an update just for the people that don't know `width` can be a percentage.

```
width: 70%;
```

Changed the width from `5px` to `70%` so it will expand with the width of the text.

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/pYH36/5/)

Comment: @Ruddy just a heads up in case you want to edit your answer with my edit. Cheers :)

Answer (score 4):

Edit:
Ruddy's solution has the same result and is more elegant so based on that, I used it recently with addition of transition, making it a bit more eye catching and I thought it would be useful to share here:

```
 a {
   display: inline-block;
   text-decoration:none
 }
 a:after {
   content: "";
   display: block;
   width: 0;
   border-bottom: 1px solid;
   margin: 0 auto;
   transition:all 0.3s linear 0s;
 }

 a:hover:after {
   width: 90%;
 }
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/andreasloukakis/7KcMr/1/)

(Original answer below)

[Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/AAkHU/) i just came up with, playing in the fiddle:

```
 <a class="bordered" href="#">I am a link, hover to see</a>


 a.bordered {  
 text-decoration:none;
 position: relative;
 z-index : 1;
 display:inline-block;
 }

a.bordered:hover:before {
content : "";
position: absolute;
left    : 50%;
bottom  : 0;
height  : 1px;
width   : 80%;
border-bottom:1px solid grey;
margin-left:-40%;
}
```

Depending on the percentages, you may play with a.bordered:hover:before margin and left position.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use this class:

```
.link:hover {
    background-image:url("YOUR-SMALL-LINE-BOTTOM.png")
}
```

like this, the line will appear when you hover over the element. And you can specify in the image, how small or big the line has to be.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating another Div for border. And adjust the width of that div according to your choice. I hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

what about this?

```
a {text-decoration:none;position:relative;}
a:hover:before {content:"_";position:absolute;bottom:-5px;left:50%;width:10px;margin:0 0 0 -5px;}
```

check this fiddle for more: http://jsfiddle.net/h7Xb5/

Answer (score 1):

```
use underline or if u want the line to be much shorter try scalar vector graphics(svg) with this you can have custom lines.
<svg id="line "height="40" width="40">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="700" y2="20" style="stroke:rgb(125,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
```